# Mars mips, How do I store a string the user entered into two buffers?

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

example:

```
  .data
  string: .space 50
  string1: .space 50


 .text
 li $v0,8
 li $a1,51
 la $a0, string
 move $t6, $a0 
 syscall

 la $a0, string1
 move $t8,$a0
 syscall
```

How can I can I store the content of "string" into string1 ? So that I have the same content stored into two different buffers.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to copy the contents of string to string1.
Assuming it's an asciiz string, it would be:

```
 # Copy asciiz string to string1
   li $a0, 0
 copy_loop:
   lb $t2, string($a0)
   sb $t2, string1($a0)
   addiu $a0, $a0, 1
   bnez $t2, copy_loop
```